# GNU Screen doesnt show colors or ascii full block

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, ascii, gnu-screen, ansi-escape

I`ve codet a simple cli app. This app uses ansi codes like \x1B[48;2;190;190;0m for color. In addition it uses ascii full block (█) to display qr-codes.
When I run my application in the normal linux bash it all works just fine, but if I run it into a gnu screen no colors are showing up and instead of an qr-code I only see many blank lines.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Each terminal type understand some set of escape sequences but not all of them. GNU screen has it's own control codes: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Control-Sequences, and don't understand ECMA-48 CSI sequences.

Comment: See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/575337/using-terminal-escape-sequences-within-gnu-screen